# Create Unique Route for Each Blog Post React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, content-management-system, blogs, contentful

I'm working on a blog site using React which incorporates the use of a CMS, in this case Contentful.

All blog posts are written/saved on the CMS. I am currently able to populate all blog posts onto my site but it appears as a continuous page where this no separation between the posts. To avoid this, I was planning on creating a unique link for each blog post and having the list of all articles on the main blog page (example below), and having the ability to click on the desired post which takes you to a page dedicated to only that one post.

Is there a way to dynamically create a unique link for each post that I am retrieving from the CMS.

**Main Blog Page**

1. Blog Post #1
2. Blog Post #2
3. Blog Post #3

Have a unique link created for each one of these articles such that the url is such a manner: "testsite.com/blog/blogpost1"

Wasn't able to find a similar question on here, though it might be that I wasn't searching for the correct terms. Appreciate the help!

**Update**

```
const BlogPostList = ({ article }) => {

const { titleheadings, body } = article.fields
const title = titleheadings.replace(/\s+/g, '')

const postBody = marked(body)

return (
    <Router>
        <li>
            <Link to={"/" + title}>{titleheadings}</Link>
        </li>
        <Route path={"/:id"}>
            <Child title={titleheadings} body={postBody} />
        </Route>
    </Router >
)}

function Child(props) {

let id = useParams()
console.log(id)

return (
    <div>
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col className="py-3" md="11">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text align="justify" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }} />
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
);
}

export default BlogPostList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Contentful DevRel here.

What you're looking for is a Router for React. A router allows you two to define URLs and routes inside of your application.

What a lot of people do is to have a dynamic route that takes a slug field as parameters. For [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) that could be like the following:

```
<Route path="/:slug">
  <Page />
</Route>
```

Then in your `Page` component you would read out the `slug` URL param and fetch the Contentful entry you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was struggling to figure out what this concept was called in React. I went ahead and tried implementing the example mentioned in your answer however as it currently stands the blog post appears directly below the link to the article without needing to click the link to the article. So rather than having the Child component appear upon clicking the blog post it is already visible leading me to believe that the routing wasn't done correctly. Apologies if this is confusing, but I went ahead and added the relevant code above.